# object detection neural network's bounding box error converging instantly during training

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch, object-detection, loss-function

I tried to make an SSD neural network for object detection. For now, i'm using 600 (700x700) training examples, i'm planning of using 1000 (I only have one class) or more if needed. However, there seems to be something really wrong with the mean absolute error of the coordinates of the predicted bounding boxes I'm using for the loss :

[image]

Here is the code for training

```py
clsLoss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='none')
bboxLoss = torch.nn.L1Loss(reduction='none')

batch_size = 32
train_iter, _ = datasetting.loadData(batch_size)

device, net = try_gpu(), model.TinySSD(num_classes=1)
trainer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=3e-4, weight_decay=5e-4)
num_epochs, timer = 11, Timer()
animator = Animator(xlabel='epoch', xlim=[1, num_epochs],
                        legend=['class error', 'bbox mae'])
net = net.to(device)
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    metric = Accumulator(4)
    net.train()
    for features, target in train_iter:
        timer.start()
        trainer.zero_grad()
        X, Y = features.to(device), target.to(device)
        
        anchors, cls_preds, bbox_preds = net(X)
        
        bbox_labels, bbox_masks, cls_labels = anchor.multiboxTarget(anchors, Y)
     
        l = calcLoss(cls_preds, cls_labels, bbox_preds, bbox_labels,
                      bbox_masks)
        l.mean().backward()
        trainer.step()
        metric.add(clsEval(cls_preds, cls_labels), cls_labels.numel(),
                   bboxEval(bbox_preds, bbox_labels, bbox_masks),
                   bbox_labels.numel())
    cls_err, bbox_mae = 1 - metric[0] / metric[1], metric[2] / metric[3]
    animator.add(epoch + 1, (cls_err, bbox_mae))
print(f'class err {cls_err:.2e}, bbox mae {bbox_mae:.2e}')
print(f'{len(train_iter.dataset) / timer.stop():.1f} examples/sec on '
      f'{str(device)}')
```

And the structure of my neural network (note that I've added a convolutional layer but it doesn't solve my issue sadly)

```py
def downSampleBlk(in_channels, out_channels):
    blk = []
    for _ in range(2):
        blk.append(nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels,
                             kernel_size=3, padding=1))
        blk.append(nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels))
        blk.append(nn.ReLU())
        in_channels = out_channels
    blk.append(nn.MaxPool2d(2))
    return nn.Sequential(*blk)


def base_net():
    blk = []
    num_filters = [3, 16, 32, 64]
    for i in range(len(num_filters) - 1):
        blk.append(downSampleBlk(num_filters[i], num_filters[i+1]))
    return nn.Sequential(*blk)


def getBlk(i):
    if i == 0:
        blk = base_net()
    elif i == 1:
        blk = downSampleBlk(64, 128)
    elif i == 5:
        blk = nn.AdaptiveMaxPool2d((1,1))
    else:
        blk = downSampleBlk(128, 128)
    return blk
```

I've tried to play with the learning rate, the epoch, the batch size and I even added a convolutional layer to experiment but nothing has worked so far. It of course outputs completely wrong predictions no matter the image I test it on.
Does anyone have any idea of what could be the culprit ?

for instance (the object to predict is the red road sign):

some training data output

[image: some training data output]

some test data output

[image: some test data output]

```py
cls_loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='none')
bbox_loss = nn.L1Loss(reduction='none')

def calcLoss(cls_preds, cls_labels, bbox_preds, bbox_labels, bbox_masks):
    batch_size, num_classes = cls_preds.shape[0], cls_preds.shape[2]
    cls = clsLoss(cls_preds.reshape(-1, num_classes),
                   cls_labels.reshape(-1)).reshape(batch_size, -1).mean(dim=1)
    bbox = bboxLoss(bbox_preds * bbox_masks,
                     bbox_labels * bbox_masks).mean(dim=1)
    #print(bbox)
    return cls + bbox

def predict(X):
    net.eval()
    anchors, cls_preds, bbox_preds = net(X.to(device))
    cls_probs = F.softmax(cls_preds, dim=2).permute(0, 2, 1)
    output = anchor.multiboxDetection(cls_probs, bbox_preds, anchors)
    idx = [i for i, row in enumerate(output[0]) if row[0] != -1]
    return output[0, idx]
```

bbox loss (don't mind the legend)

[image]

class loss

[image]

Comment: *look* at some of the training vs. inferred outputs. what do you notice?

Comment: To me It looks like it can predict neither training nor test data, though the confidence is never above 0.8 for any predicted box, so maybe I just need more training data ? I'll some outputs above.

Comment: if it can't even hit the traffic sign, why does your training claim to get tiny class error? you need to investigate your loss function(s).

Comment: Well that was my first guess however half of it is handled by pytorch itself with the respective cost functions for the class and bounding box losses and  I didn't and I still don't really see any issue with the code. But then again i'm pretty much a beginner, I followed the D2L book.

Comment: can you plot the class and bbox losses individually? what's their sum? try a product instead of a sum. -- perhaps also revisit the `mean(dim=1)` , be sure about that dimension

Comment: I've added them above

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the individual loss plots.

The magnitude of your bbox loss is **three orders of magnitude** less than the class loss.

It's basically noise, irrelevant, to the optimizer.

When you combine losses, you *should* scale them to be in the same order of magnitude. Something near one is a good idea. The magnitude of your loss resonates with the learning rate to affect the magnitude of the updates to the network.

Comment: strangely enough when I try to multiply the bbox loss by 10^3 or 4 before the sum I get mostly zeros